# Datagridview get selected cell's location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've done some search in Stackoverflow and found code which should have solved my problem, but for a reason I can't find, it just doesn't. I'll explain my issue: My form shows a question to the left, and possible answers to the right (The possible answers are in the datagridview), the moment the client clicks his answer, the answer will be updated in the database. The client CAN get back to questions already asked and see his previous answer, which will be marked by the code:

```
 DG.Rows[i].Selected = True;
```

So it seems that the blue marking is not enough and I need to add another symbol which indicates that the selected row is the one which the client already clicked.
I was asked to add a checked - checkbox next to the selected row to indicate that.
I created a CheckBox and used this code:

```
 CbAnswer.Location = DG.PointToScreen(DG.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, i, true).Location);
```

but for some reason the result is as follows:

[image]

The checkbox should be right ON row number 5.
I'd like to mention that all the possible answers are already filled in the datagridview and everytime the client clicks a cell to pick his answer an algorithm hides the 6 previous answers, and shows the 6 next ones. Does it have to do anything with my issue?

Comment: "So it seems that the blue marking is not enough" that's mean ?

Comment: That means that the client which the program is to be sold to him was not satisfied by the blue marking only, and asked another indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to check the *checkbox*

```
DG.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = true; //where 1 is the checkbox column
```

**EDIT** *(using your code)*

```
CbAnswer.Location = new Point(DG.Location.X + DG.Width, DG.Location.Y + 
               DG.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, i + 1, true).Location.Y - CbAnswer.Height);
```

Comment: What you are saying is that I need to add a column to the datagridview, with checkboxes, and check only the selected row's checkbox, which can work, although my datagridview currently doesn't contain that column. The checkbox is independent and has nothing to do with the datagridview and only to be located on the selected row.

Comment: @Skatz1990 *I was asked to add a checked - checkbox next to the selected row to indicate that*. You mean it is outside the DG?!

Comment: @γηράσκω 'my datagridview currently doesn't contain that column' it is

Comment: It could be either on the selected row or next to it (same height), it should not be a part of the Datagridview though (a column contained in the DG)

Answer (score 1):

To get the current cell try to use

```
DG.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

and

```
DG.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
```

I don't know about the blue marking though

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any different result with ?

```
CbAnswer.Location = DG.PointToScreen(DG.CurrentCell.ContentBounds.Location);
```

Comment: There is a difference in the CB's location, it's still incorrect though.
For some reason, the rectangle solution changed its location and now it's static, no matter what your answer is - the checkbox doesn't move.
Edit: I don't know why, the CB's height is always few inches below the correct height